# Flash Debug not displaying properly in Firefox Linux

Tags: firefox, plugins, mozilla, flash

I installed the debug version of flash using the script given in [this link](https://gist.github.com/laszlomiklosik/2857310). Alternatively, I also tried downloading the debug version of flash from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) and moved `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` but still it gives me problems viewing flash contained. 
P.S. - In `about:plugins` page on firefox it says that Flash is installed and enabled.

While trying to view flash content, the following is being displayed:

(On Adobe's website)

[image]

(On [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/samples/drawing_1.html) website.)

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?